# Justifying using the Fourier inversion theorem for $f\not \in L^1$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let's say I have the function $g(x) = \exp(-x)1_{[0,\infty)}$ and I would like to find another function $f$, whose fourier transform is $g$.

Since the fourier inversion theorem only works for $f \in L^1$, I would first have to show, that the original function is indeed integrable. I know that on $L^1(\mathbb R)$ the fourier transform is a continuous linear map to $C_0(\mathbb R)$, but since $g$ is obviously not continuous at $0$, I would argue that $f$ is not in $L^1$.

However, if I nonetheless try to use the inversion theorem, I get $$f= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{ix+1} $$

I let Wolframalpha compute the fourier transform of $f$ and I seem to be getting back my original function. Since I am not really familiar with complex analysis or distribution theory, this result confuses me a little bit. It seems like $f$ is not in $L^1$, but is in $L^2$. Was the usage of the inversion theorem justified here in any way? (I am familiar with the Fourier-Plancherel operator, so my intuition here was, that I just got lucky, but applying Fourier-Plancherel to our $f$, gives us back $g$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not just being lucky.

Your original function $g$ belongs to $L^2$ (it is actually in $L^1 \cap L^2)$. This means that its FT is an $L^2$ function and the inversion formula holds.

**Extended**

Given a function $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$, by Plancharel Theorem we have 
$$\| f \|_2 = \|\widehat{f}\|_2$$

It follows that the FT is an isometry from $L^1 \cap L^2$ to $L^2$. Since $L^1 \cap L^2$ is dense in $L^2$ it follows that the FT has an unique extension to a linear operator $\widehat{ \cdot } : L^2 \to L^2$.

Now, as the Fourier Inversion Formual holds on a dense subspace of $L^2$, it follows that for all $f \in L^2$ we have
$$\widehat{\hat{f}}(x)=f(-x)$$

But, be carefull. For $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$, the Fourier trasnform $\widehat{f}$ has classical meaning. If $f \in L^2$ is not integrable, the meaning of $\widehat{f}$ is 
$$\widehat{f}\stackrel{\| \, \|_2}{=}\lim_n \widehat{f_n} \\
\mbox{where} f_n \in L^1 \cap L^2 \, \mbox{ and  } f\stackrel{\| \, \|_2}{=}\lim_n f_n$$

The discussion at the top explains why this definition does not depend on the choice of $f_n$.

Comment: Okay, I see now how we can argue that $f$ is in $L^2$ before applying the inversion theorem. However, I thought that $f$ had to be in $L^1$ too, or is it sufficient for one of the functions to be in $L^1$ to apply the inversion theorem?

Comment: @GreenLogic The inversion theorem holds for $L^2$ functions. However, there is a small catch here: for functions in $L^1 \cap L^2$, the Fourier transform is defined as the integral against the exponentials/characters. To extend it to $L^2$, it is proved that the FT extends uniquely to an Isometry on $L^2$. So the FT on $L^2$ is not exactly an integral anymore, it is the limit of integrals of approximations of $f$. So when you write $\widehat{f}$ it doesn't mean the integral, it has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: @GreenLogic I added extra details, is the picture now clear?

Comment: Everything is totally clear now, thanks