# Existence of inverse Fourier transform through validity of calculations

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let \begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}e^{-x}\,e^{-\gamma \min(x,k)}&,x\ge 0\\ 0&,x<0\end{array}\quad,\gamma>0.\right.
\end{equation} 
$f$ clearly lies in $L^1$, so it's Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ is well defined. I calculated it to be 
\begin{equation}
(\mathcal{F}f)(y)=\hat{f}(y)=e^{-k(1+\gamma+iy)}\left(\frac{1}{1+iy}-\frac{1}{1+\gamma+iy}\right)+\frac{1}{1+iy}
\end{equation}
For the inverse transform to exist, $\hat{f}$ also needs to be $L^1$. I don't really know how to show this though ($\rvert\hat{f}\lvert$ is a rather complicated term (see comments)), so I just went ahead and tried to calculate it. Since the transform has a rather nice form, looking through Fourier transform tables gets me
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{f})(x)=e^{-x}\Big(\Theta(x-k)\big(e^{-k\gamma}-e^{-\gamma x}\big) + \Theta(x)e^{-\gamma x}\Big),
\end{equation}
where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function.
This is exactly the same as $f$, just using step functions.
Is this a legitimate approach to show the existence of the inverse transform? If not, why does it work out to be correct nonetheless?

Comment: you know you take absolute values for $L^1$ norms, right? so you don't need to integrate a complex function....

Comment: yes this is right, but the problem is rather that I don't know how to work out $\hat{f}$'s real and imaginary parts

Comment: okay, but that's just a problem with complex numbers rather than a problem with integration of complex functions. in any event, if you're studying the fourier transform, you should be more than able to figure out the real and imaginary parts of $\hat{f}$.

Comment: I could actually figure out the real and imaginary parts of the function now. But this form is actually quite long and rather unhandy.
\begin{align}
Re(\hat{f})=&e^{-k(1+\gamma)}\Big(\cos(ky)(\frac{1}{y^2+1}-\frac{1+\gamma}{(1+\gamma)^2+y^2})+\sin(ky)(\frac{y}{(1+\gamma)^2+y^2}-\frac{y}{y^2+1})\Big)+\frac{1}{y^2+1}\\
Im(\hat{f})=&e^{-k(1+\gamma)}\Big(\cos(ky)(\frac{y}{(1+\gamma)^2+y^2}-\frac{y}{y^2+1}-\sin(ky)(\frac{1}{y^2+1}-\frac{1+\gamma}{(1+\gamma)^2+y^2})\Big)-\frac{y}{y^2+1}\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2672321/justifying-using-the-fourier-inversion-theorem-for-f-not-in-l1) post, I can make use of the Plancherel Theorem.
The function $f$ lies in $(L^1 \bigcap L^2) $, since it's in $L^1$ and $f(x)\le 1\ \forall x$. So it's Fourier transform also lies in $L^2$ and the inversion formula holds.